# How to convert a custom list class to json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got the following class (a bit simplified version):

```
public class DemoList<K, V>
{
    private List<SomeItem<K, V>> _listItems;

    public DemoList()
    {
        _listItems = new List<SomeItem<K, V>>();
    }
    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return _listItems.Count; }
    }
    public void Add(SomeItem<K, V> item)
    {
        _listItems.Add(item);
    }
    public SomeItem<K, V> this[int index] 
    {
        get { return _listItems[index]; }
    }
}
```

The SomeItem code:

```
public class SomeItem<K, V>
{
    private K _key;
    private V _value;
    public SomeItem(K key, V value)
    {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }
    public K Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }
    public V Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

When I add some values to the demo list:

```
DemoList<String, String> dl = new DemoList<string, string>();
dl.Add(new SomeItem<string, string>("bla1", "diebla1"));
dl.Add(new SomeItem<string, string>("bla2", "diebla2"));
dl.Add(new SomeItem<string, string>("bla3", "diebla3"));
dl.Add(new SomeItem<string, string>("bla4", "diebla4"));
```

Now I'd like to convert this to json, using NewtonSoft.Json ... like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dl, serializerSettings);
```

This results in the following JSon:

```
{"Count":4}
```

The json I was hoping for is something like:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "bla1": "diabla1"},
    {"bla2": "diabla2"},
    {"bla3": "diabla3"},
    {"bla4": "diabla4"}
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i know links are often frowned upon but http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size

Comment: To be honest, I've been messing with a lot of JSON from C# lately and I've found it much easier to build a string than trying to use JSON.Net. There were just too many problems, especially when I was trying to get JSON.Parse in JavaScript or Google Charts to recognize my stuff. After the string was built, I'd just blank the calling page and write the formatted JSON to it. If you like that idea, I'll post a snippet of my code where I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Json.Net to serialize the list of items, you can either expose the items as a public property (as others have suggested), or mark the list with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute like so:

```
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    private List<SomeItem<K, V>> _listItems;
```

If you want to suppress the `Count` from the output, mark that property with `[JsonIgnore]`:

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return _listItems.Count; }
    }
```

With the above changes we get the following JSON, which is closer, but still not quite what you wanted:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "key": "bla1", "value": "diebla1" },
    { "key": "bla2", "value": "diebla2" },
    { "key": "bla3", "value": "diebla3" },
    { "key": "bla4", "value": "diebla4" }
  ]
}
```

To get the items into the format you want, you need a custom `JsonConverter` class like this:

```
class SomeItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && 
            objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SomeItem<,>);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value);
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add(token["Key"].ToString(), token["Value"]);
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        JProperty prop = token.Children<JProperty>().First();
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add("Key", prop.Name);
        obj.Add("Value", prop.Value);
        return obj.ToObject(objectType);
    }
}
```

Add the converter to your JsonSerializerSettings and serialize your list as before:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new SomeItemConverter());
var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dl, serializerSettings);
Console.WriteLine(jsonContent);
```

Now we have this JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "bla1":"diebla1" },
        { "bla2":"diebla2" },
        { "bla3":"diebla3" },
        { "bla4":"diebla4" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Brian ... thanks a million!! This indeed solves all the issues. I tested it and it works. I dont understand though how it is possible to get data from a private property in the json output simply by adding [JsonProperty("items")] ... _listItems IS private isn't it??? Anyway, as said before .. it does work perfectly! It does hide the count, it does avoid having to make a new public property Items .. love it!

Comment: @Paul0515 [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) allows one to "cheat" and access non-public properties and methods on objects.  Json.Net uses reflection to do its business, so that is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Create any method  in   DemoList that returns  _listItems. Then calling that getter method in json serializer would give the required json.

Comment: This only solves part of the problem.  The asker wanted the items in `{"foo":"bar"}` format, not `{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}` format.